# FANCYBOX: Specify the look of the close buttons

Tags: html, css, iframe, plugins, fancybox

How do I specify what style the 'close button' appears for the Fancybox Lightbox plugin?

Right now, the close button for the lightbox appears in the upper right corner. I don't like this look. I want the close button right next to the content.

HTML markup:

```
<a class="iframe" href="#">Image</a>
```

JavaScript trigger:

```
$(".iframe").fancybox();
```

[Here's the close buttons I want. Click here!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwlLl.jpg)

---

Fancybox Plugin:
http://fancybox.net/

Comment: It's all pulled from the following [image](http://fancybox.net/js/fancybox-1.3.4/fancybox.png)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display small close button over the content, then set like this:

```
$('[data-fancybox="modal"]').fancybox({
    smallBtn : true,
    toolbar  : false
});
```

Demo - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YQWoWd

Styling is up to you, you can change it to your taste using CSS, for example, like this - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WOxqOx

Comment: Thank you! This is more what I had in mind.... But, it's still not working for me. I am referencing a class name. Can it still work in this way:

    $(".iframe").fancybox({
      smallBtn : true,
      toolbar  : false
    });

Comment: It does not matter what selector you use, just make sure it selects your element :) And make sure to use the latest from v3.1